# Typescript Omit does not show error when using reference

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

interface objInterface {
  first: string;
  second: string;
}

const obj = {
  first: "first",
  second: "second"
};

const out: Omit<objInterface, "first"> = obj;
```

I was expecting this to have some intellisense errors, but it does not. This however does show some errors, anyone know why?

```
const out: Omit<objInterface, "first"> = {
  first: 'first',
  second: 'second'
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TS only errors on excess properties when defining the object as a literal, by design. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @kingdaro's correct point about excess property checks on object literals,

The definition of `Omit<T,K>` just widens the type of `T` so that it does not contain a *known* property at `K` ("I don't know or care if `K` is a property; I will ignore it."), which is not the same as *prohibiting* a property at `K`.  That is, `T` is a subtype of `Omit<T, K>`, and any value of type `T` will be also be assignable to type `Omit<T, K>`.  If your intent is to actually *prohibit* a property at `K`, you can (kind of) do this by specifying that the `K` property is optional and has a value type of `never` (or `undefined`, see below).  Let's call that `ForcefullyOmit<T, K>`:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type ForcefullyOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<Record<K, never>>;
```

And let's see if it works:

```
interface ObjInterface {
  first: string;
  second: string;
}

const obj = {
  first: "first",
  second: "second"
};

const out: ForcefullyOmit<ObjInterface, "first"> = obj; // error
// types of property "first" are incompatible
// string is not assignable to undefined
```

Looks good.

It's only "kind of" prohibiting the key, since it will still allow a property at that key of type `undefined` (or `never`), but that's kind of an [unresolved issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) in TypeScript... the language doesn't always distinguish between missing properties and `undefined` ones.

It's up to you if your use case really needs the stricter behavior of `ForcefullyOmit`. Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!